# angular : Define route with extension

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router

How can I define an angular 4 route with .html in the pattern?

Example: Say the url is mydomain.com/collections/test.html. When I get the route params in a component, I want to retrieve 'test' as the value, and not 'test.html'

File where routing is defined

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'collections/:tag.html', component: CollectionDetailsComponent},
];
```

In CollectionDetailsComponent.ts

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) =>
    {
      let tag = params['tag'];
//Here tag contains ".html" at the end
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that Angular is for single page applications? What's the purpose for having `.html` at the end?

Comment: yes, I think I've read something about this.  Alll urls must be accessible directly from search engines, and I was asked to have these urls ending with .html (even if I don't see the point). I don't get to decide, just implement it. So...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only 2 ways

add a dummy child route (with the name of your choice of cource)

```
{path: 'collections/:tag/dummy.html', component: CollectionDetailsComponent},
```

add `.html` to the value

```
 {path: 'collections/:tag', component: CollectionDetailsComponent},
```

and use `foo.html` as tag value.

I haven't tried if `.` in the URL causes any issues, but I think to remember that there were related bug reports a long time ago which were fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure that there was no "proper" angular way of doing this. I went with option #2 but I manually strip '.html" off the value